# What's the safest way to reset permission to default?

Tags: security, permissions, user-accounts, users

I have mixed permissions on winodws 10 from trying to backup windows.old file and windows-bt. I added "Everyone" to the user names and groups list but there's a red icon on the administrator account with an X it has "special Permissions" I haven't found a single thing I couldn't do on the computer I was even able to update and play games on it.

1. How bad is this and how vulnerable is my computer? Again I haven't found anything I couldn't do or any errors and I'm the only one that uses this laptop. It does have kasperky.
2. What's the safest way to undo these changes? I found a method for it using the cmd but it's seems risky from the mixed results I read from other users and I don't want to make things worst than they already are if they're bad.
   How do I know what profile I'm using and what permssions it has? I'm aware that
3. I'm using a local account on windows 10, but when I check the users in the task manager I see the original name from before I changed it. Is there a way to switch to the administrator (not the hidden one) account? and is there a way to make my local account an administrator?
4. What is the interactive account?
5. What's the difference between the administrator and the administrators accounts?

(update) I recieved a reply from joeqwerty "icacls  /reset /t" but I'm not sure if that is a command for CMD or a directory.

Comment: Every version of Windows has a built-in account name Administrator, a user account you created, can be placed into the Administrator user group and thus be an Administrator.  The rest of your questions are not clear.  Have you performed research so you understand what, `icacls /reset /t`, does?  [Using icacls to set permissions of a folder to inherit recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327776/using-icacls-to-set-permissions-of-a-folder-to-inherit-recursively)

Comment: You have to go to the directory that you want to reset permissions in command prompt and then use `icacls /reset /t`.