# Restore program files on Symbolic Linked OS with Junction?

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link, restore, ntfs-junction

Is there a way to restore Windows Registry, Paths and confguration if I have a NTFS-Junction link to `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `ProgramData` and `Users`?

I'm wondering if I can fully restore my OS (Windows 10) with it's programs configurations and Users folder and data after doing some clean install.

This is actually the hierarchy of my files:

```
D:\ -> USER_DATA (Stores C:\Users)
P:\ -> PROGRAM_DATA (Stores Program Files and ProgramData folders)
G:\ -> GAME_DATA (I install here my games lol)
```

Is there a way to restore programs in a clean Windows install?
I mean, I don't want to reainstall everything I have after formatting. Can I do this?

Comment: Unless you change the permissions on the files, even if you setup a junction point, the permissions on the files will be a problem.  Why don't you reset the ACL on the files you want to transfer?

Comment: Related: [What's the safest way to reset permission to default?](http://superuser.com/questions/1123136/whats-the-safest-way-to-reset-permission-to-default#comment1605678_1123136)